# Have OpenSSH quit if `Match exec` command does not return 0

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-config

I'm using the SSH `Match exec` functionality to trigger a script when making a connection, such as:

```
Match host foo* exec "/some/script.sh"

Host foo
 User ubuntu
 [... rest of ssh config file truncated ...]
```

The problem I am facing is that ssh will proceed with any connection regardless of the exit code of the script called with exec (`/some/script.sh` in this case).

Is there any way to get it to stop everything (don't proceed with ssh connection) if the script exits a non-zero code?

Answer (score 3):

Note: if the role of the script was known, other possibilities would be possible rather than just prevent the connection. For example if the script is to determine if a laptop is currently using/not using some specific network, then instead of derailing a connection, it could for example use a `ProxyJump` through an intermediate server for connectivity.

---

Assuming the script exits with a value different than 0 when failing, you can invert the script's return condition using `!` to enable a configuration that will make the connection fail when the script fails (of course you could instead invert the script's exit code). Then parameters below the `Match` line will be used only when the script fails.

```
Match host foo* exec "! /some/script.sh"
    ... some settings to derail the connection: see below ...

Host foo
 User ubuntu
 [... rest of ssh config file truncated ...]
```

I don't know of an option that specifically prevents to connect, but some parameters can be used to derail a connection.

Any parameter(s) that will guarantee a connection failure can be used. Some features might depend on the OS. Below are a few example lines to use in replacement of `... some settings to derail the connection: see below ...` to have a connection failure:

- an alternate address and port using `Hostname 127.0.0.1` and `Port xxxx` to be sure it connects to somewhere where nothing is listening

  ```
  Hostname 127.0.0.1
  Port 2345
  ```

  which would get, only if the script failed:

  ```
  $ ssh foo
  ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 2345: Connection refused
  ```

  - with root access one can dedicate a failing IP address for this (and no need to change port):

    Example on Linux as root:

    ```
    ip route add unreachable 192.0.2.2/32
    ```

    Then just:

    ```
    Hostname 192.0.2.2
    ```

    giving:

    ```
    $ ssh foo
    ssh: connect to host 192.0.2.2 port 22: No route to host
    ```
- (Linux) bind to the `lo` interface, making routing fail

  ```
  BindInterface lo
  ```

  giving:

  ```
  $ ssh foo
  ssh: connect to host foo port 22: Invalid argument
  ```

  But this won't prevent ssh to itself (eg: if `foo` is the system's own address).
- unknown host

  ```
  GlobalKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking yes
  ConnectTimeout 1
  ```

  This will still attempt the connection but will then fail because it will never find the fingerprint provided by the host:

  ```
  $ ssh foo
  No ECDSA host key is known for foo and you have requested strict checking.
  Host key verification failed.
  ```

  Of course this is inadequate in case the script failure was related to connectivity issues, but a timeout can mitigate this, getting this instead after only 1 second:

  ```
  $ ssh foo
  ssh: connect to host foo port 22: Connection timed out
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Haven't read yet, but responding to "if the role of the script was known" comment in your response: The script triggers some MFA flows that enable SSH access on the remote system (which is a jump host/bastion). Successful connection is impossible until the script executes successfully so I wanted to just abort if it fails.

Comment: Having tested I was ready to post the same (type of) solution. But then I saw you'd easily pipped me to it! Maybe add `BatchMode yes` to avoid any prompts

Comment: So, to confirm I'm understanding correctly: You're saying that there really isn't a way to have to simply stop any processing/abort, and instead, I can force some connection params that guarantee failure. If that's the case, my connection will already fail anyways if the script fails so I guess I'm already accomplishing this workaround. Thanks so much for the info.

Comment: I'm saying that I don't know there's any. I might be wrong, or there might be none today and something made in the future to address this. Meanwhile this would get the job done.